# How to configure linum-mode in spacemacs?

Tags: cc-mode, linum-mode, spacemacs

How can I configure [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) to always have `linum-mode` active in C/C++ buffers (`cc-mode`)?

Comment: There goes the StackOverflow mantra: "what have you tried?". When asking questions of this kind it's best to tell what you have already tried to prevent obvious answers (in this case the obvious answer is to add `(linum-mode)` to the `c-mode-hook`.)

Comment: not really, the question is spacemacs specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is specific to spacemacs then you can add this line in your `dotspacemacs/config`:

```
(add-to-hooks 'linum-mode '(c-mode-hook c++-mode-hook))
```

Comment: This might be obvious but I'm new to spacemacs and I have to ask. Where exactly is this dotspacemacs/config file?

Comment: Never mind I found it. in .spacemacs file:
(defun dotspacemacs/config ()
  (add-to-hooks 'linum-mode '(c-mode-hook c++-mode-hook))
)

Comment: Is this still valid ? I get `Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol's function definition is void: add-to-hooks`

Comment: @nha: The function is now called spacemacs/add-to-hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You could put this in `dotspacemacs/config`:

```
(global-linum-mode)
(with-eval-after-load 'linum
  (linum-relative-toggle))
```

The relative number line will be by default.

Comment: For me the `(global-linum-mode)` was not needed, just the next two lines.